# Angular js service value does not updates in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I'm using the stateProvider, and when the state is changed i want to update my breadcrumbs in the header. Instead of writing for each state its own embedded view, i just put on the service that shares the array of breadcrumbs with their names and links, when some state is being called function inside of each controller sets its own value of this array, i can see in the debugger how the value inside the service is being updated, but the view is not refreshed is there any suggestions? 
Code: Header controller:

```
$scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbs;
```

The view:

```
<md-button ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs" ui-sref="{{breadcrumb.link}}"> {{breadcrumb.title}} </md-button>
```

Service:

```
.service("breadcrumbsService", function Breadcrumbs() {
        var self = this;
        self.breadcrumbs = [
            {title: "Home", link: "KeyStyle.home"}
        ];
    });
```

Any other controller code:

```
 .controller("ownerRegistrationController", ["$scope", "Owner", "$http", "domain", "breadcrumbsService",
        function ($scope, Owner, $http, domain, breadcrumbsService) {

            updateBreadcrumbs();
...
        function updateBreadcrumbs() {
                breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbs = [
                    {title: "Home", link: "KeyStyle.home"},
                    {title: "New owner", link: "KeyStyle.home.owner.registration"}
                ];
            }
```

Comment: [$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) the change that `updateBreadcrumbs` does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you re-assign `breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbs`, you are breaking the reference established in `$scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbs;`

Instead, you should `push` new entries on to the array. It should also trigger a digest cycle (`$scope.$apply()`) or be run on the next one (`$scope.$applyAsync`)

```
function updateBreadcrumbs() {
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
        breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbs.push({
            {title: "New owner", link: "KeyStyle.home.owner.registration"}
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why `applyAsync`? Is it because it is faster than `apply`?

Comment: @Vidul I mentioned you can use either. I prefer async for view updates so you can queue them instead of triggering a new cycle for each one

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed!